# Boost Polygon Serialization: Ring

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, boost-geometry

According to this related question ([Boost Polygon Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959723/boost-polygon-serialization)). I am trying to serialize polygons with Boost. The problem I have now is that I am trying to compile an example using polygons of custom X, Y, points, but the compiler throws this error at compile time:

```
error: 'class boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> >' has no member named 'serialize'
```

Like there is no defined any function to serialize a ring. Since a Ring extends from std::vector, and as stated in the related question, it is not necessary to define a method for its serialization. But the compiler complains.

Here I have a full example about defining polygons, and its serialization:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy< double > point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::ring< point > ring;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon< point > polygon;

namespace boost{
        namespace serialization{

                template<class Archive>
                inline void serialize(Archive & ar, point &point, const unsigned int file_version)
                {
                        std::cout << "Point: Serializing point" << std::endl;
                        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("x", point.x());
                        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("y", point.y());
                }

                template<class Archive>
                inline void serialize(Archive & ar, polygon &t, const unsigned int file_version)
                {
                        std::cout << "Polygon: Serializing outer ring" << std::endl;
                        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("outer", t.outer());

                        std::cout << "Polygon: Serializing inner rings" << std::endl;
                        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("inners", t.inners());
                }
        }
}

using namespace boost::geometry;
using namespace boost::archive;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        polygon poly;
        append(poly, make<point>(0.0, 0.0));
        append(poly, make<point>(5.0, 5.0));
        append(poly, make<point>(5.0, 0.0));
        correct(poly);

        ofstream ofs("polygon.xml");
        xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(poly);
}
```

Any idea about how to get this working?

**EDIT: Fully functional code about polygon serialization**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/tracking.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy< double > point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::ring< point > ring;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon< point > polygon;

namespace boost{
        namespace serialization{

                template<class Archive>
                inline void serialize(Archive & ar, point &point, const unsigned int file_version)
                {
                        std::cout << "Point: Serializing point" << std::endl;
                        ar & const_cast<double &>(point.x());
                        ar & const_cast<double &>(point.y());
                }

                template<class Archive>
                inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ring &ring, const unsigned int file_version)
                {
                        std::cout << "Ring: Serializing ring" << std::endl;
                        ar & static_cast<std::vector<point>& >(ring);
                }

                template<class Archive>
                inline void serialize(Archive & ar, polygon &t, const unsigned int file_version)
                {
                        std::cout << "Polygon: Serializing outer ring" << std::endl;
                        ar & t.outer();

                        std::cout << "Polygon: Serializing inner rings" << std::endl;
                        ar & t.inners();
                }
        }
}

using namespace boost::geometry;
using namespace boost::archive;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        polygon poly;
        append(poly, make<point>(0.0, 0.0));
        append(poly, make<point>(5.0, 5.0));
        append(poly, make<point>(5.0, 0.0));
        correct(poly);

        BOOST_FOREACH(point& p, poly.outer())
        {
                std::cout << "point " << p.x() << "," << p.y() << std::endl;
        }

        ofstream ofs("polygon.dat");
        binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << poly;
        ofs.close();

        polygon polyFromFile;
        ifstream ifs("polygon.dat");
        binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> polyFromFile;

        BOOST_FOREACH(point& p, polyFromFile.outer())
        {
                std::cout << "point " << p.x() << "," << p.y() << std::endl;
        }
        ifs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even when partial specialization for serialzation exists for `std:vector<T>` this does not imply it will work for subclasses, so you have to add a serialization method for `ring`:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ring &t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    // Impl
}
```

So what's in the implementation? As `geometry` is not built to be serialized, you cannot access types that would be useful for the serialization (for example, to select the correct default implementation for the container `ring` inherits), so you can force this somehow. For example, this seems to work:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ring &t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
     std::cout << "Ring: Serializing a ring" << std::endl;
     serialize(ar, static_cast< std::vector<point>& >(t), file_version);
}
```

You can also try to write some base class serialization call:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(Archive & ar, ring &t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
     std::cout << "Ring: Serializing a ring" << std::endl;
     ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp( "Base",
              boost::serialization::base_object<std::vector<point> >(t));
}
```

but again, the problem is that you should be able to access that inherited class from within `ring`. In fact, it *is* in the definition of `ring`, as `base_type`, but it is private to the class. If it was public, you could write the not so bad code using `ring::base_type` as a parameter for the serialization (instead of the bare `std::vector<point>` above).

Maybe knowing the inners of the serialization library you can "tie" the serialization machinery so that two calls are not neccessary, specializing some partial specialization for the `ring` class itself, but I doubt this would be portable.

Comment: Pretty insightful. I like your closing thoughts. Exactly the sort of thing that might be worth suggesting to the Boost Geometry devs

Comment: perfect answer! thanks! I was so close to your solution, however i was serializing the ring with "ar & static_cast...", not calling serialize method... It was compiling ok with serialization, but failing to compile with deserialization code with constantness errors

Comment: The same problem as my approach, when calling serialize with the static cast, the code for serializing seems to work, but when adding deserialization, it throws another error like 'basic_binary_iprimiteve.hpp:88:9: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'

Comment: Finally get it working... Not happy with const cast in point, but i prefer that rather than split its serialization... thx for your help!

Comment: Mmm... `serialize` (without splitting) works both ways, right?

Comment: Well, calling "serialize" from "serialize" is not recommended by Boost.Serialize documentation. I give a version which works correctly; quite similar to what Diego suggested in the end.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla serialize was failing with point.x() and point.y() when deserializing, since .x() and .y() returns a const reference. I solved that with const_cast as suggested in boost.

Comment: @MichaelSimbirsky and calling with & as done in my example? I think that it is right...

Comment: Using & is correct. As a side note, I do not fancy you using "const_cast" in Point serialization here. Essentially you break in into internals of geometry::point. Besides, it might not work well if point has extra fields. Typical solution would be to have "serialize" with two sections. `if typename archive::is_saving()` similar to yours. The section `else` would init two local vars x and y, deserialize them and then assign to the point.

Comment: Good point @MichaelSimbirsky. I commented that preferred the const cast prior to splitting serialization. But this is a good argument to split save and load. thx

Answer (score 0):

As @Diego Sevilla pointed above, the major obstacle is that base_type is declared as private within `ring<...>`. It is a bit weird as the inheritance is in fact public.

Still, one can slightly generalize his solution by using detailed definition of the geometry::model::ring

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization{
    template<class Archive,  //other template params are from model::ring
             typename Point,
             bool ClockWise , bool Closed ,
             template<typename, typename> class Container, //= std::vector,
             template<typename> class Allocator// = std::allocator
             >
    void serialize(Archive & ar,
                   geometry::model::ring<Point, ClockWise, 
                                        Closed, Container, Allocator> & rng,
                   const unsigned int version)
    {
        typedef Container<Point, Allocator<Point> > ring_base_type;
        ring_base_type & contour = rng;
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(contour);
    }
} //namespace serialization
} //namespace boost
```

It should work correctly for almost any variant of boost::geometry::model::ring.

Comment: I see, but you tie the definition to the *exact* implementation of `ring` actually. It may change in the future.

Comment: Agree. As for the future, there are two alternatives. First, one can change serialization to match the class `ring<...>`. Second, one can use more generic serialization based on __concept__ of ring; it means essentially saving and loading a generic random-access range of points. Will be slightly less efficient, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for boost::geometry to string serialization:

boost::geometry::wkt
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/io/wkt/wkt.html

and this for unserialization:

boost::geometry::read_wkt
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/io/wkt/read_wkt.html

works perfect.